# Como ler arquivo .txt?

Tags: java, android

Como eu faço para ler um arquivo `.txt` que é escrito em linhas e verificar se em uma linha desse arquivo tem um valor caso tenha realizar um cheque no `checkbox`.

Exemplo:

### Arquivos txt:

```
123
234
2456
```

Se tem o arquivo `123`, checa o `checkbox 123`, eu não preciso que o arquivo `txt` fique visível ao usuário só preciso que o código faça a leitura dele.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Para ler um .txt a partir do android, tu pode utilizar o seguinte código:

```
try {
    AssetManager assetManager = getResources().getAssets();
    InputStream inputStream = assetManager.open("nome-do-arquivo.txt");
    InputStreamReader inputStreamReader = new InputStreamReader(inputStream);
    BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(inputStreamReader);
    String linha;
    LinkedList<String> linhas = new LinkedList<String>();
    while((linha = bufferedReader.readLine())!=null){
        //aqui com o valor da linha vc pode testar o que quiser, por exemplo: linha.equals("123")
        linhas.add(linha);
    }
    inputStream.close();
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: Alexandre, a noite vou fazer o teste e retorno aqui.
Desde já agradeço.

Comment: Resolvido Alexandre.

Comment: @MatheusArruda ok! Qualquer dúvida, é só avisar!

Comment: @AlexandreStrevenski em qual pasta o arquivo txt deve ficar?

Comment: @ramaral sei que a reposta não e sua, mas você poderia me informar qual pasta deve ficar o arquivo txt.

Comment: @Rodolfo dentro da pasta 'assets'.