# Dúvida sobre ler arquivos txt no Android?

Tags: java, android

Com base nessa pergunta do [stackoverflow](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/85518/java-android-ler-arquivo-txt) na reposta é sugerido esse código

```
try {
    AssetManager assetManager = getResources().getAssets();
    InputStream inputStream = assetManager.open("nome-do-arquivo.txt");
    InputStreamReader inputStreamReader = new InputStreamReader(inputStream);
    BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(inputStreamReader);
    String linha;
    LinkedList<String> linhas = new LinkedList<String>();
    while((linha = bufferedReader.readLine())!=null){
        //aqui com o valor da linha vc pode testar o que quiser, por exemplo: linha.equals("123")
        linhas.add(linha);
    }
    inputStream.close();
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

A dúvida é com mais variáveis qual o comando para ele ir pulando alinha e armazenado o valor na variável dentro do `while`.
e a **principal dúvida qual pasta deve ficar `arquivo txt` no Android?**, pois só é passado o nome do arquivo.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Vamos lá:

**1.**

> A dúvida é com mais variáveis qual o comando para ele ir pulando
>   alinha e armazenado o valor na variável dentro do while.

Isto é feito dentro da condição do `while`:

```
while((linha = bufferedReader.readLine())!=null)
```

Note que ele adiciona a variável `linha` o valor de `bufferedReader.readLine()`. E isto ocorrerá até ser diferente de `null`.

De forma mais simples:

```
 String linha ="";
 LinkedList<String> listLinhas = new LinkedList<>(0);
 while(linha !=null){ // enquanto não for null..
     linha = bufferedReader.readLine();   // lemos a próxima linha...
     listLinhas.add(linha); // adicionamos a linha na LinkedList
 }
```

**2.**

> E a principal dúvida qual pasta deve ficar arquivo txt no Android?,
>   pois só é passado o nome do arquivo.

Na pasta Assets, para que possamos utilizar o `AssetManager`.

Segue como criar esta pasta:

No Android Studio clique com o botão direito na pasta [image: app] e navegue até Assets Folder.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Após confirme clicando em finish, e a pasta será criada:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 4):

Da forma como o código da pergunta se encontra, o arquivo de texto deve estar na pasta assets.

Porém, segundo esta resposta no **[SOEn](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19833144/5524514)**, você pode criar uma pasta chamada `raw` dentro da pasta `res`(caso já não exista) e salvar o arquivo de texto lá, assim, ele se torna um recurso acessível como `R.raw.meuArquivoTXT`:

```
String result;
    try {
        Resources res = getResources();
        InputStream in_s = res.openRawResource(R.raw.meuArquivoTXT);

        byte[] b = new byte[in_s.available()];
        in_s.read(b);
        result = new String(b);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // e.printStackTrace();
        result = "Error: can't show file.";
    }
```

Mais informações podem ser encontradas na documentação:

http://developer.android.com/intl/pt-br/tools/projects/index.html