# Comparar dados do SMS com arquivo txt

Tags: android

Estou tentando criar um aplicativo em que eu recebo um SMS que vai conter um código, exemplo "AC0012", então vou ler essa informação, e comparar ela com com meu arquivo `.txt`.

Esse arquivo `.txt` vai conter varias linhas, e cada linha terá informações como essa: "AC0012 - Avenida São Carlos - Centro".

Então se o código do SMS for igual ao código do `.txt`, eu vou jogar na tela "Avenida São Carlos - Centro" e emitir um som de como se tivesse chegado mensagem nova. Não sei se o arquivo em `.txt` é o melhor para fazer isso. Eu até tentei ler o arquivo que está na pasta *Asset* e depois comparar a *string* do código linha a linha do arquivo `.txt`, mas não consegui nem ler o arquivo direito, deu vários erros.

Então deletei tudo e vim atrás de ajuda para implementar esse app.

Abaixo o básico que já fiz.

**Classe que recebe o SMS e o transforma em um *String***

```
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.telephony.SmsMessage;


public class RecebeSMS extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        // Recebe o sms
        Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();
        Object[] messages=(Object[])bundle.get("pdus");
        SmsMessage[] sms=new SmsMessage[messages.length];
        String codigo = "";

        if (bundle != null){
        // Recuperando mensagem recebida
            for (int i = 0; i<messages.length; i++){
                sms[i]= SmsMessage.createFromPdu((byte[]) messages[i]);
                codigo += ", Codigo: ";
                codigo += sms[i].getMessageBody().toString();
                codigo += "\n";
            }


        }

    }
}
```

**Classe principal:**

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class givetheaddress extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_givetheaddress);
    }
}
```

Comment: E que tal usar uma Base de Dados? Estás programar em Android?

Comment: Seria uma boa, eu até procurei algo sobre SQLiteOpenHelper, mas como sou novo mexendo com Android achei que seria mais complexo. Mas vamos lá, aceito sugestões :D

Answer (score 2):

Se a quantidade for muito grande, sugiro você salvar as informações em um banco de dados.

Senão, para ler um arquivo `txt` localizado na pasta Assets :

```
 public void searchCode (String smsCode){
        try {
            AssetManager assetManager = getResources().getAssets();
            InputStream inputStream = assetManager.open("nome-do-arquivo.txt");
            InputStreamReader inputStreamReader = new InputStreamReader(inputStream);
            BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(inputStreamReader);
            String linha ="";

            while(linha !=null){
                linha = bufferedReader.readLine(); // lemos linha por linha
                if(linha.contains(smsCode)){
                    /**
                     * Aqui vai suas ações
                     */
                }

            }
            inputStream.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

[Aqui tem exemplo](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/114458/d%C3%BAvida-sobre-ler-arquivos-txt-no-android/114495#114495), que explica até como criar a pasta!

Outra opção é criar a lista no `String Resource` do Android:

Dentro a pasta `res > values` existe um arquivo chamado strings.xml

[Segue a documentação](http://developer.android.com/intl/pt-br/guide/topics/resources/string-resource.html)

Você também pode criar um arquivo com um nome específico, como por exemplo:

**codigos.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
 <string-array name=“codigos_array“>
   <item>AC0012 - Avenida São Carlos - Centro</item>
   <item>AC0013 - Avenida B - Bertioga</item>
   <item>AC0014 - Avenida C - São João</item>
  </string-array>
</resources>
```

Para ler o array:

```
public void searchCode (String smsCode){
    final String[] values = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.codigos_array);

        for(String linha : values){
            if(linha.contains(smsCode)){
                /**
                 * Aqui vai suas ações
                 */
            }

        }

}
```