# Como manipular arquivos de texto no Android?

Tags: android

Eu tentei procurar em vários sites, mas cada um indicava de uma forma diferente. Eu sei como implementar os objetos para criar e ler um arquivo em java, usando `File`, `FileWriter`, `BufferedWriter`, `FileReader`, `BufferedReader`, e era bem simples o entendimento. O problema é que no Android você precisa de uma permissão pra gravar/ler arquivos.

Alguns tutos dizem que é possivel gravar no SD virtual do Android sem Problemas(e sem precisar de permissao),o problema é que o SD Virtual é um arquivo img não tem como abrir pelo computador e verificar se o arquivo foi criado ou nao. Já outros dizem que tem como criar na propria pasta do projeto onde esta a classe(eu tentei fazer isso usando o mesmo algoritmo,mas sem sucesso).

Alguém pode me explicar como gravar/ler arquivos `txt` com essas classes que eu citei?

Comment: [Dúvida sobre ler arquivos txt no Android?](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/114458/28595)

Comment: [Como criar um arquivo txt no Android?](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/82498/28595)

Comment: Dica, quando elaborar uma pergunta, atente-se a escrever um texto mais organizado, foi dificil ler seu texto até o final sem ter que voltar toda hora,